# excel debugger active and prevent to run another excel file properly

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, break, xlsm

I create a excel file with user login form that works correctly .when user open the excel file, login form appear and he can insert username and password and login easily. but the problem is that: if I first open another xlsm file and breaks its vba code an excel go to debug mode, and then I open our file, excel open without showing login window (because debugger is active).
what can I do??

how can add a code to my file to reset or stop debugger at first??

Comment: Excel VBA is single-threaded.  The only wat to do this would be to open the login file in a new Excel instance.